# Why does PHP cURL drop numeric keys?

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to use cURL to POST an array containing numeric indices, but curl_setopt is dropping the numeric indices. I'm using PHP Version 5.3.29.

Here's a simple script I setup to illustrate what is happening:

```
<?php

$is_curled = isset($_GET['curl']) ? !!$_GET['curl'] : false;

if (!$is_curled) {
    $url = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI'] . '?curl=1';

    $_POST['1'] = 'test1234';               // dropped because numeric
    $_POST[234] = 'test3211';               // dropped because numeric
    $_POST['t3'] = 'test1325';              // NOT dropped
    $_POST['4t'] = 'test6347';              // NOT dropped
    $_POST['_5'] = 'test3235';              // NOT dropped
    $_POST['*4'] = 'test7432';              // NOT dropped BUT gets the NEXT POST value
    $_POST["3"] = 'test8521';               // dropped because numeric
    $_POST['"2"'] = 'test9472';             // NOT dropped because the string "2"
    $_POST["'1'"] = 'test2741';             // NOT dropped because the string '1' BUT gets the NEXT POST value
    $_POST["10"] = 'test1738';              // dropped because numeric
    $_POST['test_field'] = 'test6123';      // NOT dropped

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST);       // this drops numeric keys

    echo '<pre>' . print_r($_POST, 1) . '</pre>';

    curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

} else {
    echo '<pre>' . print_r($_POST, 1) . '</pre>';

}

?>
```

Here is the output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => test1234
    [234] => test3211
    [t3] => test1325
    [4t] => test6347
    [_5] => test3235
    [*4] => test7432
    [3] => test8521
    ["2"] => test9472
    ['1'] => test2741
    [10] => test1738
    [test_field] => test6123
)
Array
(
    [t3] => test1325
    [4t] => test6347
    [_5] => test3235
    [*4] => test8521
    ["2"] => test9472
    ['1'] => test1738
    [test_field] => test6123
)
```

What's even weirder, is not only are some indices dropped, but the values appear to be shifted in the ones next to the ones that are dropped.

Comment: The workaround I did was instead of using curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST); I just assembled an URL string myself and posted that.

Comment: `http_build_query()` is your friend

Comment: What is the output of `print_r($_REQUEST);` ?

Comment: @OliverQueen the output is the same as $_POST but with the addition of [curl] => 1

Comment: In PHP 5.6.17 it only drops ["2"] => test9472, and does not shift the values.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your sending content type  `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` means you're sending HTML Form data.  (PHP curl defaults to this content type as it is the w3c recommended default https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4).

According to the spec, **NAME** tokens (a.k.a. the `post` and `get` parameter names )have to start with an letter:  https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#h-6.2

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

This is probably why it's not being handled as you expect, because starting a param in the POST body with a number for the indicated content type is unsupported.

Comment: It makes sense that POST params that start with numbers are invalid, but why doesn't it just drop all those invalid ones. It only drops the numeric ones, not the other invalid ones that start with a number and contain letters.

Comment: Also why does it shift the values? It seems to drop the numeric ones and grab the value for the next index.

Comment: @pfela You'd probably need to look at the source to figure out exactly why an unsupported state is handled differently in some cases and other.  I'd guess it wasn't a conscious call, they we coding to meet the the standard, and didn't need to handle cases that were outside that.  Thus you can't expect any consistency in what you get--if you do find a pattern, I still recommend avoiding straying outside the norm of what's expected for a given content type.